# Cannot use msbuild from docker image in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have found a docker image with msbuild and nuget installed. I want to use msbuild to build my .NET framework project, but it returns the following error:

[image]

```
$ & "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly
& : The term 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...Bin\MSBuild.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is my yaml file:

```
.shared_windows_runners:
  tags:
  - shared-windows
  - windows
  - windows-1809
variables:
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Nuget\nuget.exe'

stages:
  - build

build:
  extends:
  - .shared_windows_runners
  stage: build
  image: compulim/msbuild
  script: 
    - echo "start building"
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly'
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" WebCICD\WebCICD.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /P:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml'
    - Tree
```

I found this docker image by googling "docker msbuild image".
I thought the image could let me use the file path to build the project directly. Am I wrong?
Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `'& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH"` try just `msbuild`

Comment: When I just type msbuild it turns out another error: 
msbuild : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I have also been struggling with '& "$env... Have you tried to replace this MSBUILD_PATH with its actual value (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe)?